# $scope.user.id outside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase

I'm using angular.js and AngularFire and using their chat example. THe point is that the user logs in, then i should set `var trueRef` to `new Firebase("https://alfapixteste.firebaseio.com/users/" + $scope.user.ie)` so when the user pushes messages, they go to his own table....

The problem is that i can't get `user.id` when I declare `var trueref`. The `alert()` works fine when user submits a message

Here's my full code
As you can see, I even tried to set the $scope.user.id outside the function, it works

```
var app = angular.module("atendapp", ["firebase"]);

function MyController($scope, angularFire, angularFireAuth) {
    //Login e Logout

    $scope.login = function () {
        angularFireAuth.login("facebook");
    };
    $scope.logout = function () {
        angularFireAuth.logout();
    };
    $scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function (evt, user) {
        $scope.meuid = user.id
    });
    var ref = new Firebase("https://alfapixteste.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.messages = [];
    var ide = $scope.meuid;
    var trueref = new Firebase("https://alfapixteste.firebaseio.com/usuarios/" + ide)
    angularFireAuth.initialize(trueref, {
        scope: $scope,
        name: "user"
    });
    angularFire(trueref, $scope, "messages");
    $scope.addMessage = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
        alert($scope.meuid)
        $scope.messages.push({
            idusr: $scope.user.id,
            from: $scope.user.name,
            body: $scope.msg
        });
        $scope.msg = "";
    };
}
```

Oh, trueref returns 'undefined'

Comment: It is probably because $scope.meuid is not set when the controller is created, but after the login, so trueref was already called by then. In the exemple, there is not this async problem. You could try to move the code inside the login event.

Comment: As @jpmorin points out `$scope.meuid` is only set after the login succeeds. You need to move your trueref call to after login succeeds.

Comment: if i change the block with angularFire(trueref and also trueref to the upperblock (login) it does not work

Comment: I believe i'm having a hard time to separate the login from the content. the content should be added only after login right?